# SQL Conditional calculations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables. They have 1 to many relations

```
table1 - mainID, Select00(bit), Select01(bit)
table2 - secID, mainID
table3 - secID, Num00, Num01



SELECT  table1.mainID ,  SUM(table3.Num00) as S00, SUM(table3.Num01) as S01
FROM    table1 INNER JOIN
        table2 ON table1.mainID = table2.mainID INNER JOIN
        table3 ON table2.secID = table3.secID
GROUP BY table1.mainID HAVING table1.mainID =11
```

The following query works, but gives me all sums.

How do I get the SUMs based on  condition? i.e

```
S00 = SUM(table3.Num00) if table1.Select00 = 1 (true)
S01 = SUM(table3.Num01) if table1.Select01 = 1 (true)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.mainID,
    S00 = SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Select00 = 1 THEN t3.Num00 ELSE 0 END),
    S01 = SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Select01 = 1 THEN t3.Num01 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    dbo.table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2
    ON t1.mainID = t2.mainID
    INNER JOIN dbo.table3 AS t3
    ON t2.secID = t3.secID
WHERE t1.MainID = 11
GROUP BY table1.mainID;
```

Comment: Great! Any advantahge in using WHERE vs HAVING?

Comment: Just habit. HAVING usually is used to filter out on aggregates (which is why it is logically after the GROUP BY), for example HAVING SUM(...) > 10. WHERE filters out before the grouping - I suspect it's either more efficient or, at worse, as efficient as using HAVING (though I'd be happy to be proven my long-standing assumptions are wrong).